# AVAudioPlayer not playing sound from temp file path

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I have saved a recording to my **Temp directory** and can verify this using **iExplorer**

The file path structure is `TempFolder/UserID/SoundName001.wav`
The bit I save to the database is `UserID/SoundName001.wav`

Here is the code I use to play the file

`@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;`

```
-(void) playSound: (NSIndexPath*)recordingIndex {
    NSArray *recording = [recordingArray objectAtIndex:recordingIndex.item-1];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(),[recording objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSURL *recorderURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: filePath];
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorderURL error:nil];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player setMeteringEnabled:YES];
    [self.player setDelegate:self];
    [self.player play];
}
```

I set a breakpoint and `recorderURL` returns the following `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0883D0DC-B1FD-4D06-A7BB-EBD9EEF5D607/tmp/1/Dog001.wav`

[image: Photo evidence]

When I call this method, nothing happens, no crash, no sound...
Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the silent switch on your device? I think AVPlayer doesn't play sound if the silent switch is turned on. Try putting this line of code:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];`

in your `viewDidLoad` or before `[self.player play];` and see if the audio plays.